# FCM/GCM for electron APP

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, electron, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been using FCM/GCM to send notifications to Chrome App, Chrome Extension, Android APP.

But, may I know how can I send notifications to an electron APP from FCM/GCM. I browsed through a lot of websites but did not find anything related to it.

PS: I don't worry about how the notifications are displayed. I just want the notification payload to be received by the electron app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there currently is a way to receive FCM/GCM notifications in an Electron app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing available out of the box with Electron but there is a Node package available here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-push-receiver

There's no boilerplate code available for using this package yet, but there is an open issue in the associated GitHub project requesting a working example: https://github.com/MatthieuLemoine/electron-push-receiver/issues/8